# Why hasOwnProperty returns false?

Tags: json, node.js

I cant understand why hasOwnProperty return false on the following scenario:

Client side:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var client = [
                            {"clientName":"", "clientNickName": ""},
                            {"clientName":"", "clientNickName": ""},
                            {"clientName":"", "clientNickName": ""}
                         ];         



            function onSubmit() {

                // update data
                client[0].clientName = "AAA";
                client[0].clientNickName = "BBB";
                client[1].clientName = "CCC";
                client[1].clientNickName = "DDD";
                client[2].clientName = "EEE";
                client[2].clientNickName = "FFF";               

                // create request
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                   
                xmlhttp.open("POST","~/process_post",true);     
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");               

                // send
            xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(client));                                   

                return true;
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body >

        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post" method="POST">                                        

            User Name:
            <input type="text" name="userName">
            <br>    
            Nick Name:
            <input type="text" name="nickName">
            <br>    

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onSubmit()">
            <br>                        
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.post('/process_post', function (req, res) {   

   var x = req.body;
   if  (x[0].hasOwnProperty('clientName')) {
    console.log("yes: clientName exsists");
   }

   console.log("result: " + req.body);
})



var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

- I have updated the Q, after get some comments which didnt help.
- Why the server does not parse the json data properly ?
  The server crash when calling hasOwnProperty on x[0]:
  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Thanks

Comment: You are sending an array. The `client` and `clientName` properties exist on the array items, not the array itself. Try `x[0].hasOwnProperty('clientName')`.

Comment: Doesnt work, it crash (TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined)

Comment: Check what data is actually being sent to the server

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you cannot send an array as a raw object.

You need to send a string representation of it.

Use `xmlhttp.send( JSON.stringify(client) );`

---

Then, when you do `var x = req.body;` you assign the array to the `x` variable.

So you need to test its items for the property you want and not the array itself.

Try `x[0].hasOwnProperty('clientName')`

Comment: I have tries your suggestion, but didnt help (I have updated the thread... you can check it and see yourself)...

Comment: Have you checked what `req.body` actually is on the server ?

Comment: What do I need to check ?